# Get summarised data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a table

| Name | Salary | Desc2 | Desc3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 9 | X | X |
| ABC | 9 | X | X |
| ABC | 9 | X | X |
| XYZ | 4 | Y | Y |
| PQR | 1 | Z | Z |
| PQR | 1 | Z | Z |
| PQR | 1 | Z | Z |

I want it something like :-

| Name | Salary | Desc2 | Desc3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 27 | X | X |
| XYZ | 4 | Y | Y |
| PQR | 3 | Z | Z |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:

```
=Query({A1:D8}, "select Col1, sum(Col2), max(Col3), max(Col4) group by Col1",1)
```

Comment: Could you explain why the use of max() ??

Comment: min and max are your only two options for collapsing text, it basically just selects alphabetically in case there is variance in that column.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the columns to be considered are those from A to D and that row 1 is reserved for headings, you could try this formula:

```
=query(A1:D,"select A,sum(B),C,D where A is not null group by A,C,D ",1)
```

Comment: I like to always wrap references in {} in a query so I can use the Col1 format because if you move a single column it messes up your entire string.